# How To Recreate The Bullet Time Slow Shutter Effect From Fight Club?

Tags: python

There is a scene in Fight Club that I won't link to as it is very NSFW and I'm sure that's not allowed here, but it is a bullet time sequence done entirely in CGI that features a very original simulation of a slow shutter speed that you would get in an actual camera for a photo. I have obtained the actual steps it took for the VFX studio to achieve these shots from someone that worked there, but for the slow-shutter effect they programmed their own piece of software. I found something close for Blender but it utilizes multiple cameras and that isn't quite the effect, as it is influenced by the animation of the characters. Here are the steps:

1. Early version of what we would think of as photogrammetry / scans today for the people.
2. Bodies are mostly unlit textures with baked lighting.
3. Bodies have basic deformer rigs with a single animation arc between 3 or 4 poses.
4. A script runs at render time to change the rig animation (not camera) to make the renderer think it moves really far on an arc over the course of the blur shutter. Imagine over the shutter blur samples the whole body rig is animating from the normal frame 0 to frame 100, and you did 100 samples cross your blur, on each frame. So you see the full blurred animation, every frame.
5. Camera shutter blur is cranked way higher than normal.
6. End result is this cool blur effect where it looks like they are in bullet time every frame.

So it's pretty straight forward except for Step 4. Is this possible to do in Blender using Python? Thank you again for your continued help and support.

Example Shot From The Movie:

[image]